# Cannot access field criteria on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<id STRING, totalResults INT64, resultType STRING, ...>>

Tags: google-bigquery, unnest

I have multiple levels in the Bigquery column names, and after using UNNEST, I'm still getting the error shown in the title.

`SELECT name1.name2.name3.name4 FROM table` -- error

`SELECT n1.name2.name3.name4 FROM table, unnest(name1) as n1` --still error, this time for name4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after using multiple unnests; one for every name that gives the error:

`SELECT n.name4 FROM table, unnest(name1) as n1, unnest(n1.name2.name3) as n`